# How can I fix this?

Tags: tables

How to produce the following table in LaTex:
[image]

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

%Some packages I commonly use.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor} %For coloring texts and objects

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % to allow characters beyond ASCII (e.g. à, ü, č ...)
\usepackage[top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{authblk} %For Author Titling and affiliating Purpose

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Name of Student / Teacher} & 
        \multirow{2}{*}{Years of Study} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Subjects} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{Years of Passing} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{Class/rank /distinction} &
        \multirow{2}{*}{University/ Institute} \\
        \cline{3-4}& & Main & Subsidiary & & & \\
        \hline
        
        Science & 2013-2016 & Mathematics & Physcs, Chemistry & 1929 &  & Name of the University Here\\
        \hline
        Name & 2016-2018 & Biology & Chems & 1997 &   & University Name Here\\
        \hline
        (Last item) & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But my texts in the cells are getting overlapped with each other.

**My Output**

[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT**
As suggested in the comments I modified it as follows

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

%Some packages I commonly use.

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{xcolor} %For coloring texts and objects

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % to allow characters beyond ASCII (e.g. à, ü, č ...)
\usepackage[top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{authblk} %For Author Titling and affiliating Purpose

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{Name of Student / Teacher} & 
        \multirow{2}{=}{Years of Study} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Subjects} &
        \multirow{2}{=}{Years of Passing} &
        \multirow{2}{=}{Class/rank /distinction} &
        \multirow{2}{=}{University/ Institute} \\
        \cline{3-4}& & Main & Subsidiary & & & \\
        \hline
        
        Science & 2013-2016 & Mathematics & Physcs, Chemistry & 1929 &  & Name of the University Here\\
        \hline
        Name & 2016-2018 & Biology & Chems & 1997 &   & University Name Here\\
        \hline
        (Last item) & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**New OUtput**

[image]

Still it's not that what I want.

Comment: We do not have your file 'structure'. Would you please complete your code to a MWE with the relevant packages you use?

Comment: Using `\multirow{2}{=}` instead of `\multirow{2}{*}` could be the first step.

Comment: @C.Peters I have added that portion here.

Comment: @leandriis Okay I tried yours it gets better this time but some portion remains as before.

Comment: @indrajit: That's why I wrote "first step". Replacing `\multirow{2}{*}` with `\multirow{2}{=}` won't magically fix all issues with this table. First of all: How exactly do you want to fix the table? Would you be satisfied with using a smaller font size in your table and slightly different column widths in order to make sure all column header fit into one or two lines? Or do you want to stick with the given font size and column widths, while at the same time allowing column headers to take up three rows without protruding into the table row below?

Comment: Also, are you aware, that your table currently is quite a bit wider than the textwidth of your document?

Comment: @leandriis I don't want to reduce the font size but it would be nice if height of the first row can be larger.

Comment: Off-topic: No need to load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`. I'd recommend loading and using just `enumitem`.

Comment: @Mico Thankyou,

Comment: Note that `top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in` may be written more succinctly as `margin=1in`.

Comment: You might want to consider a more informative title for your question. `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested a version in which the font size is not altered. In order to make sure, the table fits into the available text width, I used the `tabularx` package and altered some column widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[top=1 in,bottom=1in, left=1 in, right=1 in]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ |p{1.8cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.8cm}|X|}
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{=}{Name of Student / Teacher} & 
        \multirow{3}{=}{Years of Study} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Subjects} &
        \multirow{3}{=}{Years of Passing} &
        \multirow{3}{=}{Class/rank /distinction} &
        \multirow{3}{=}{University/ Institute} \\
        \cline{3-4}& & \multirow{2}{=}{Main} & \multirow{2}{=}{Subsidiary} & & & \\
        &&&&&&\\
        \hline
        
        Science & 2013--2016 & Mathematics & Physcs, Chemistry & 1929 &  & Name of the University Here\\
        \hline
        Name & 2016--2018 & Biology & Chems & 1997 &   & University Name Here\\
        \hline
        (Last item) & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @lendriis I used this in my original file but there the last column gets smaller and that's why texts in the last column is getting out of the table ! Can please you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Off-topic:

- the package `hyperref` should be load the last in the preamble
- don't use `enumerate˙ and` enumitem` packages, please use only one of them
- don't affray to use some new package which can simplify your code and gives better result

On topic:

- with the `tabularray` package solution is quite simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={|X[1.3]|X[0.8] |X[1.1]|X[0.9] |X[0.8,c]|X[0.8] |X|X[1.5]|},
                 colsep=3pt,
                 rowsep=3pt,
                 hline{1,6}={1pt}, hline{3}=0.6pt,
                 hlines
                }
\multirow{2}{=}{Name of Student/ Teacher} 
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Years of Study} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Subjects} 
                &   \multirow{2}{=}{Years of Passing}
                    &   \multirow{2}{=}{Class/ rank/ distinction}
                        &   \multirow{2}{=}{University/ Institute} \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   &   Main 
            &   Subsidiary 
                &   &   &                                           \\
Science 
    & 2013-2016 
        & Mathematics 
            & Physcs, Chemistry 
                & 1929 
                    &   & Name of the University Here               \\
Name 
    & 2016-2018 
        & Biology 
            & Chems 
                & 1997
                    &   & University Name Here                      \\
(Last item) 
    &   &   &   &   &   &                                           \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show text borders)

Comment: It gives the error: ``` File 'tabularray.sty' not found```

Comment: @indrajit, this means that your LaTeX installation doesn't contain this package. Load it (by help of utility of your LaTeX installation, for example by MiKTeX Console, if you have MiKTeX).

Comment: I have MikTex console installed in my Ubuntu system. I tried to install the package with name ```tabularray``` but I didn't find any package with this name. Although I found a package named ```tabulary```. Are they same?

Comment: @indrajit: [`tabulary`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) and [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) are *not*  the same package.

Comment: @indrajit, try to update your MiKTeX installation, refresh file names database and update package database.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Something like this? (Note: Not a single `\multirow` as far as the eye can see...)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\input{structure} % I don't have access to 'structure.tex'
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % or whatever is appropriate
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
% utility macro for typesetting header cells:
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
   \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} M{\hsize} @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
   
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ |M{2.1cm}|M{1.6cm}|M{1.8cm}|M{1.8cm}|M{1.4cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.2cm}|}
        \hline
        \mytab{Name of Student\slash Teacher} & 
        \mytab{Years of Study} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Subjects} &
        \mytab{Years of Passing} &
        \mytab{Class\slash rank\slash distinction} &
        \mytab{University\slash Institute} \\
        \cline{3-4}
        & & Main & Subsidiary & & & \\
        \hline
        
        Science & 2013--2016 & Mathematics & Physics, Chemistry & 1929 &  & Name of university here\\
        \hline
        Name & 2016--2018 & Biology & Chems & 1997 &   & University name here\\
        \hline
        (Last item) & & & & & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does my job. Is it possible to get this output by using those packages which I have used originally?

Comment: @indrajit - My solution uses the `array` package for its `\newcolumntype` macro and the `ragged2e` package for its `\RaggedRight` macro. Both your sample code and my solution make use of the `geometry` package. The nine other packages loaded by your sample code -- `graphicx`, `hyperref`, `xcolor`, `enumerate`, `enumitem`, `booktabs`, `multicol`, `multirow`, `amssymb`, and `inputenc` -- can not duplicate the machinery of the `array` and `ragged2e`packages. (But do note that you shouldn't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`.)

Comment: Thank you so much